# Alphabetically ordering vocabulary terms in a translated

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I have 5 English-Italian terms in a views exposed filter:

Academic | Accademico
American Studies | Studi americani
Medieval Studies | Studi medievali
Music | Musica
Reviews | Recensioni

The English language appear in alphabetical order and, as you can probably guess, the rendering order for the Italian translation is:

Accademico
Studi americani
Studi medievali
Musica
Recensioni

The desired order is:

Accademico
Musica
Recensioni
Studi americani
Studi medievali

I sort of halfway understand what is happening here. My question is whether this is something that is best remedied by hook_form_alter() or whether there is some obvious translation configuration I am missing in Views?

Comment: Are you showing results in both languages at the same time? And showing the Exposed filter options in two languages at the same time? If not can you share more about your Views language settings?

Comment: The English-language list appears on the /en page; the Italian-language list appears on the /it page. They do not appear on the same page. Views settings are very straightforward including rendering language set to "Interface text language selected for page"; using the Basic exposed form; and the exposed filter limited to selected items. The view correctly sorting English language terms alphabetically and applying the same sort order to the Italian translation without accounting for the fact that the Italian language translations appear in different order when ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I just faced the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I found an old solution for Drupal 7 and just changed it until it worked. ;)

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  if (array_key_exists('MYEXPOSEDFILTERKEY', $form)) {
    asort($form['MYEXPOSEDFILTERKEY']['#options']);
  }
}
```

It's fairly simply and works as at that point the options are already translated. So, you just need to sort the options in the respective filter.